# Reading CSV's in D3 v5 JS: Why am I having trouble grabbing data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

I want to write imported data from a CSV to a webpage. I can do it with the traditional method of reading a CSV below:

```
  d3.csv("day.csv",function(data) {
  d3.select("ul").append("li")
  .text(data.Endangered).style("color","brown");
 });
```

However, when I attempt to use the most recent way for d3 v5, it is not working for me.

```
 d3.csv("day.csv").then(function(data) {
     d3.select("ul").append("li")
    .text(data.Endangered).style("color","brown");
  });
```

Perhaps I am not doing something correctly.

Comment: have you looked at the console if you have a CORS problem? Look at the server logs to see if your request arrives

Comment: Just for future reference, the accepted answer has nothing to do with the alleged problem in the question. I'm voting to close it anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not iterating the data. In D3 you should join the data into your selection and then based on your data, create the DOM nodes.

Maybe this will help:

```
d3.csv("day.csv").then(function(data) {
  d3.select("ul") // where dom nodes will be appended
  .selectAll("li") // elements that should be bound with array items
  .data(data) // add array with data
  .enter() // join data and selection nodes
  .append("li") // If data has more indexes than your li selection, the missing elements will be created
  .text(d => d.Endangered)
  .style("color","brown");
});
```

Comment: We can see that this is a useful answer. However, it doesn't answer the question: why OP's code didn't work with the `then` method in v5 while it worked with the callback in v4?

Comment: OP's snippet is too short to achieve a conclusion. To be honest, just with the code given, I don't even know how it could have worked in v4.

Comment: Exactly. Therefore, in a case like this, the adequate action is voting to close as *"unclear"* or *"questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it"*. However, what we have now is a Q/A pair completely disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll pay more attention next time. However, I disagree that the code is completely disconnected since that to achieve what OP described with version D3 V5, my proposed changes would have to be made.

Comment: Great. But I'm not talking about the code: I'm saying that the question and the answer are disconnected. Also, your changes would be needed for the v4 version working as well. So, this has nothing to do with v4/v5 differences.